# Plotly Dash - Bootstrap's cards don't change of color

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I am trying to change the color of some Cards, the problem is that neither the background color nor the border color change.
In this code fragment I try to color the first Card, but it is observed that it is exactly the same as the others below:

```
dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.Div([html.H3("Nº DBpedia entities"), html.H3("123")]
                                         )]),style={'display': 'inline-block'}, color="secondary", inverse=True),
dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.Div([html.H3("Nº DBpedia types"), html.H3("188")] 
                                         )]), style={'display': 'inline-block', "margin-left": "30px"}),  
dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.Div([html.H3("Nº redirects"), html.H3("888")] 
                                         )]),style={'display': 'inline-block', "margin-left": "30px"}),
dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([html.Div([html.H3("Nº disambiguations"), html.H3("777")] 
                                         )]),style={'display': 'inline-block', "margin-left": "30px"})
```

Result:
[image]

Hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You haven't included the bootstrap styles, see linked answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will test it tomorrow.